# Introductory Algebra Book Suggestions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, reference-request, soft-question, self-learning, book-recommendation

### General Requirements

The algebra book must be no more than 400-500 pages in length and should contain end-of-lesson/chapter exercises.

### Required Topics

- linear equations
- linear inequalities
- graphing and analyzing linear functions
- systems of equations and inequalities
- multiplying and factoring expressions
- quadratics(everything about polynomials)
- functions
- ratios and proportions

(and even more if the book has it...)

Comment: all of these things would be covered in any basic algebra textbook.

Comment: it's odd...I looked at many of them and some either lack graphs(for the functions) or lack exercises...

Comment: Unfortunately, most interesting techniques for graphing are beyond the level you seem to be looking for, which may explain why the texts you've found have little about it.

Comment: Besides the books already mentioned, you might also want to look at [Algebra 2 and Trigonometry by Mary P. Dolciani](http://www.amazon.com/dp/039534378X), the standard U.S. Algebra 2 text back in the 1960s and 1970s. If it's of any interest, I went through this book cover-to-cover back in Fall 1973.

Answer (score 4):

Gelfand's [Algebra](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0817636773) book is fantastic. It is written for the student to enjoy.

Lang's [Basic Mathematics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387967877) also sounds like a good choice. It's between 400 and 500 pages, but contains more than you asked for.

The [Art of Problem Solving](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Store/curriculum.php) algebra and precalculus books are very good, if you're looking for books with a contest prep focus (they're still great, if not).

Alternatively, you could work through Khan Academy's [knowledge map](https://www.khanacademy.org/exercisedashboard).

Answer (score 2):

I teach a college algebra class at a state university in New York and have found that my students have great success with this book.
[http://www.amazon.com/Intermediate-Algebra-College-Students-Developmental/dp/0321620917](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321620917)

I'm sure you can find a cheap used copy, perhaps an older edition. I have been using this book since the fourth edition, it's basically unchanged.

Answer (score 2):

I am taking a Pre-Calc Coursera course and they use http://stitz-zeager.com/szprecalculus07042013.pdf, which I like thus far and I think it meets your criteria, except for length. I think Exercises and the included answers to those exercises preclude a book in the 500 page range.