# What would be a good book to self study basic algebra?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, reference-request

I am asking about basic algebra so that I can tie it into learning about number theory and set theory. before I tackle Geometry, and College Algebra/Analytical Geometry. I will top it off with Spivak's Calculus and Shifrin's Multivariable Calculus.

Comment: I know it's not a book, but KhanAcademy.org actually has very good coverage of basic algebra IMO, both in terms of videos and exercises. Have you tried it?

Comment: I can't do online. I need a physical copy of a book.

Comment: nitrous2's answer to [Relearning from the basics to Calculus and beyond.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/427868/relearning-from-the-basics-to-calculus-and-beyond) has some good suggestions. See also the suggestions at [Math Textbooks for High School](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/186555/math-textbooks-for-high-school) and [Need an algebra book](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/625296/need-an-algebra-book).

Comment: The textbook I am currently using for a mathematical reasoning course is "Introduction to Mathematical Thinking: Algebra and Number Systems". It is quite good, mainly uses algebra and number theory as well as number systems to learn proof techniques.